# How do I save a screen capture in memory and use Ctrl+P to paste it on other application (e.g Outlook)

Tags: c#, clipboard

I am writing a small tool such that I can click a button and it will capture the screen as an image:

```
Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
Size s = this.Size;
m_memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(m_memoryImage);
memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
```

But then I would like to paste that screen on another application such as outlook when I press Ctrl+P, just wonder how can I make it happen?

Comment: Maybe you mean ctrl+v?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clipboard.SetImage(m_memoryImage);
```